Stupid buddy film with a party and a girl that's really the devil
There was a movie I caught a few minutes of a few weeks back. It was newer, but old enough to be on premium channels.
It was a ridiculously stupid horror/comedy about a group of guys that threw a party (not Project X). People started dying, but they didn't want to raise alarms because they wanted to get laid.
There was a celebrity that played himself that ended up dying. They brought him down (Weekend at Bernie's style) to get him out of the house. Somebody noticed him, started saying how much he loves him. When he asks why he isn't responding, the kids say he's just hammered.
Then there was a scene where there was a hot chick about to sleep with the one kid. She ended up being the devil, and wanted them to join her. They all ended up fighting.
As I said, it was ridiculously stupid. Still, it's bugging me that I didn't catch the name of the movie.

Kind of sounds like one of the Scary Movie franchise installments. I haven't seen any of those so I can't confirm.

Sounds like Killer Pad, a 2008 horror comedy directed by Robert Englund.

Three naive guys, in their 20s, drive from Illinois to LA. A sleazy real-estate agent gives them a great deal on a house in the Hollywood Hills. The night they arrive, a solitary Mexican, who speaks only Spanish, tries to warn them that the place is possessed by Satan. They don't understand him, move in, and plan a party after they meet Lucy, their gorgeous neighbor from down the hill. An old friend of theirs, studying to be a priest, joins them. In the basement is a portal to Hell, so at the party, guests meet their end in various ways. Lucy and her friends may not be who the lads think. 

Joey Lawrence appears as himself and dies and the girls are actually demons. Here's the trailer [Warning: Raunchy scenes involving a bulldog, a dwarf and a golden Speedo]:




That's it! Man, I love this site. Instead of racking my brain for weeks at a time trying to figure it out, I need to just head this way. Thanks!!
